# Mac randomisation with systemd?

Tags: networking, systemd, mac-address

Is it possible to randomise the mac address with systemd itself? I have heard that it is possible in newer versions of systemd.
This is my systemd version:

```
systemd --version
systemd 229
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ -LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN
```

But the link files just are not there.

Answer (score 4):

You can set `MACAddressPolicy` to `random` in your network device configuration file aka the [*systemd.link*](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.link.html) file e.g. `/etc/systemd/network/40-wlan-mac.link`:

```
[Match]
Driver=iwlwifi
Type=wlan

[Link]
Name=wl0
MACAddressPolicy=random
```

If you have no custom `.link` files, the default `MACAddressPolicy` is specified in the upstream `.link` file in `/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` and it applies to all devices.

Comment: I don't seem to have any of those files. So I guess that that subsystem of systemd is not implemented in my distro.(Ubuntu 16.04)

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: @MarioKamenjak - well, I don't use Ubuntu (and I'll never use it) so I can't help you there. You could just create `/usr/lib/systemd/network/99-default.link` yourself and see if it works, by default it has three lines: `[Link]` then `NamePolicy=kernel database onboard slot path` then `MACAddressPolicy=persistent`

Comment: OK I will try it later. Thank you anyways!

Comment: How can one apply the modification on the fly? Is there something I need to restart, possibly not the whole machine? The manpage mentions something called `net_setup_link`, but apparently nothing else has got this name.

Comment: @Dacav - try bringing the iface down, `systemctl daemon-reload` and then bringing the iface back up... (if it doesn't work then prolly you'll have to remove and re-add the network device with a daemon-reload in-between)... also, if you just want to change it to some random address that you pre-generated for this session only then `ip link set dev [interface] address [XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX]` but that's a whole different question...